# NHibernate FlushMode.Commit auto saves dirty objects

Tags: nhibernate, commit, flush, autosave

I seem to miss something here :

I have an application that uses a session per application method and using lazy loading.

I've set the session FlushMode.Commit and it seems that NHibernate still auto saves my dirty objects to the DB (SQLCe) although I never begin a transaction and commit it.

can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

some of my code :

```
    public Repository(ISessionProvider sessionProvider)
    {
        _sessionProvider = sessionProvider;
        _session = _sessionProvider.OpenSession();
        _session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
    }

    public IList<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        var criteria = _session.CreateCriteria<T>();
        var list = criteria.List<T>();
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Implicit transactions are created if you do not create one by code as one would expect they are also auto committed. Use `FlushMode.Never` if you do not need this behavior.

Comment: also note that the (n)hibernate team discourages the use  of session per application

Comment: OK, I guess the best thing here to do is to change the way I work with the session and make it a better practice with NH. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had another thread that was flushing the same session while I was creating a dirty object in my UI, I guess it was just a bug in my application.

works Great now, still using a session per application since I need the Lazy feature.

Comment: Congrats on figuring this one out!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' (using the green checkmark) so that others in the community can learn from your success.  Cheers~